# Having trouble installing jekyll-import on OS X 10.8

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, jekyll

I try to install jekyll-import with:

`sudo gem install jekyll-import`

And I get this error:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'jekyll-import' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: jekyll-import
```

I then went to rubygems.org and saw that there is only a beta version so I tried:

```
sudo gem install jekyll-import --pre
```

And I get the error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll-import:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for libxslt/xslt.h... yes
checking for libexslt/exslt.h... yes
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv_open() in -liconv... no
checking for iconv_open() in -liconv... no
checking for libiconv_open() in iconv.h... no
checking for libiconv_open() in -liconv... no
checking for libiconv_open() in -liconv... no
-----
libiconv is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --with-iconv-dir
    --without-iconv-dir
    --with-iconv-include
    --without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
    --with-iconv-lib
    --without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/lib
    --with-xml2-dir
    --without-xml2-dir
    --with-xml2-include
    --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
    --with-xml2-lib
    --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
    --with-xslt-dir
    --without-xslt-dir
    --with-xslt-include
    --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
    --with-xslt-lib
    --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib
    --with-libxslt-config
    --without-libxslt-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-libxml-2.0-config
    --without-libxml-2.0-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-libiconv-config
    --without-libiconv-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-iconvlib
    --without-iconvlib
    --with-iconvlib
    --without-iconvlib
    --with-iconvlib
    --without-iconvlib
    --with-iconvlib
    --without-iconvlib


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.5.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.5.9/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

I try to install libconv with MacPorts and apparently I already have it... I've been smashing my face against they keyboard all day because of this. Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the problem.

Apparently the libiconv that I had wasn't compiled for the correct architecture, x86_64, and jekyll-import and nokogiri needed i386.

The solution was to install the universal libiconv library. I did this by using mac ports and installing the libiconv port universal variant.

```
sudo port install libiconv
sudo port install libiconv +universal
```

I also had to install libxml2 and libxslt like this. After that everything was perfect.